# Passing SubClass Variable in sendSynchronousRequest Method in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, swift

I have the following code:

```
var error : NSError?
var response : NSHTTPURLResponse?


var urlData : NSData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest
    (
    request,
    returningResponse: &response,
    error: &error
    ) as NSData
```

`returningResponse` takes an instance of `NSURLResponse` as mentioned in the reference docs.

Im using `NSHTTPURLResponse` which is a subclass of `NSURLResponse`. This works fine in Objective-C but I do not know how to write this in Swift because the compiler throws an error on that line.

The error is:
`Cannot convert the expression's type 'NSData' to type 'inout NSHTTPURLResponse'`

What does this mean? and how to get it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing a different type than the method is expecting. You should still pass in `NSURLResponse`. You can cast the type afterwards:

```
var urlData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest
    (
    request,
    returningResponse: &response,
    error: &error
    )
if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
    // Work with HTTP response
}
```

Also note, the type of urlData can be inferred from the return type of the method. There is no need to specify the type nor convert the result to NSData so I removed both of those.

Comment: Thanks Man. Saved me a lot of hours